# Guard Ruby On Rails 3.2 Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spork, guard, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm following along with the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/).

Things are working pretty well, but I noticed that Guard only runs after I save some files (view or controller files), but doesn't run when I save others (routes or spec files).  I've got Guard hooked up to Spork, not sure if that matters.

When I looked at the console window running Guard/Spork, I noticed an error after I saved the non-running tests:

```
Exception encountered: #<LoadError: no such file to load -- /Users/Tyler/Development/FirstRails/sample_app/spec/routing
```

I'm not sure what the syntax of the Guard file is, I just copied the example.   Here is the Guard file:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass=>false, :cli => '--drb' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # my edits
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) do |m|
   ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing}spec.rb",
   "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_${m[2]}_spec.rb",
   "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
   "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"]
 end

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#     {m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#    {m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')                        { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
  # Capybara request specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end

guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
  watch('test/test_helper.rb')
end
```

In particular, my edits:

```
  # my edits
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) do |m|
   ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing}spec.rb",
   "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_${m[2]}_spec.rb",
   "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
   "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"]
 end
```

I do not have a spec/routing folder.

Anybody see a simple typo?  Or is there some other consideration I need to have?

I'm on rails 3.2

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have spec/routing directory, why are you watching it? :-)

Comment: I was just following along with the tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
 ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing}spec.rb",
```

Notice the second `}` between `routing` and `spec`

Now reads:

```
 ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
```

Also explains the missing directory shananigans.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment on your answer Tyler (maybe because I'm new here), but I think you've repeated a few lines in the Guardfile:

```
watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
```

I've noticed this is running tests twice; removing the duplicate lines solved this.