# Error with running Guard process: can't find singularize method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I followed the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) on setting up automated tests with [Guard and Spork](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#sec:advanced_setup). Every once in a while, especially when **saving an unedited template in my editor**, Guard will complain ([full backtrace](http://pastebin.com/dSeTPSrj)):

```
ERROR: Problem with watch action!
undefined method `singularize' for "layouts":String
```

My Guardfile:

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :all_after_pass => false, :cli => '--drb' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  do |m|
    ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
     "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb"] ### Look here ###
  end
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
    "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb" ### Look here ###
  end
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')                        { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
  # Capybara request specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$})          { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end


guard 'spork', :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('Gemfile')
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
  watch('test/test_helper.rb')
end
```

Guard doesn't complain if I restart, but restarting is getting a bit annoying; admittedly, not as annoying as running `rspec` every time I want a test.

- I tried the suggestion in [this post](http://expertbeginner.com/2010/11/14/rspec-rails-1-3-3libautotestrails_rspec-rb38-undefined-method-singularize/), but I think `.autotest` may be the wrong file for guard, since this isn't fixing the issue.
- The [only similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102483/guard-ruby-on-rails-3-2-tutorial) I found with Google doesn't seem related.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Actually, [in the Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#code:guardfile) they're adding `require 'active_support/core_ext'` at the top of the Guardfile.

I think this might fix your issue.

Also be sure to declare the spork guard before the rspec guard.

Comment: Yep, `#singularize` is from [ActiveSupport::Inflector](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html), so `require 'active_support/inflector'` is sufficient.

Comment: Doh! If it was a full code example, I would have copied-and-pasted. :D Hopefully this will help the unlucky soul who has this problem in the future. Also, thanks for the tip about guarding spork first!

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out guys. It saved a lot of my time.

Comment: Helped me too when I wanted to add a watch to factories and needed singularize. Love StackOverflow! It's made "Google the problem" so much easier. :)